# Проверка таблицы. MySQL и Java

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица, которая хранит в себе значения `username` и `money`.
Как вставить в нее значения, которые обновляются имея следующий [класс](http://pastebin.com/swquZhfZ).

Суть в том, что если юзернейма и суммы нет в таблице, то и значения не записываются, а далее соответственно не изменяются. Как это исправить?

Получить юзера, которого нужно добавить в таблицу можно функцией acc.getName()

Comment: Смотрите класс который делает insert в таблицу st_users, в приведенном вами классе предполагается уже существование записи для каждого юзера. Почему есть аккаунты которых нет в этой таблице?

Answer (score 2):

Сделать проверку? Выполнить запрос *Update*. Если ошибка такая-то, то запрос *insert*. Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я очень плохо знаю sql и поэтому пришел сюда. И опять же, не знаю как правильно создать эти проверки. В общем, полный ноль, но проблему решить как то надо. Есть вариант костылить при регистрации на сайте, но бд удаленная от сайта, на другой машине, поэтому придется тоже очень сильно запотеть.

Comment: Посмотрите про try catch(обработка исключений)и простейшие запросы sql(в вашем классе есть подобное)

Comment: Хорошо, погляжу. Спасибо.